# Ubuntu 12.04: Virtual console is dimmed

Tags: screen, power-management, virtual-console

My fresh installation (with updates ...) of ubuntu 12.04 (64bit, Desktop) automatically dims the virtual console as soon as a switch to one. After pressing ctrl+alt+fX, the screen starts dimming until it is completely black after 4-5 sec. Unlike normal power saving, the console stays black even after keystrokes (i can login) until i switch back to X. Back in X, the screen just "undims" until it has normal brightness.

It might be worth to point out that I don't even have a laptop but a standard desktop pc.

So what can I do ?

This is **NO** duplicate of [How to permanently disable monitor power saver using the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61291/how-to-permanently-disable-monitor-power-saver-using-the-command-line). As I said, the virtual console is dimmed even if X is not running!

Comment: This may help http://askubuntu.com/questions/61291/how-to-permanently-disable-monitor-power-saver-using-the-command-line