# ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64bit - screen goes black every 15 seconds

Tags: screensaver

I am completely at a loss. On a new installation of Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64bit my laptop screen has started to go black every 15 seconds. If I move the mouse or click then the display returns (I do not have to log in). Because this happens every 15 seconds the laptop is essentially unusable. It looks like screensaver behaviour but it could be anything.

If I type `sudo lshw -C video | grep product:` I get -

```
product: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
product: GM108M [GeForce 940M]
```

If I type `sudo lshw -C video` I get -

```
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:44 memory:f0000000-f0ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff ioport:4000(size=64)
  *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM108M [GeForce 940M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f1000000-f1ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:3000(size=128)
```

If I type `xset s off` this seems to have no effect.

If I type `gnome screensaver` I get -

```
** (gnome-screensaver:5014): WARNING **: screensaver already running in this session
```

If I type `xscreensaver` I get -

```
The program 'xscreensaver' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing: sudo apt install xscreensaver
```

If I type `xset -q` I get -

```
Keyboard Control:
  auto repeat:  on    key click percent:  0    LED mask:  00000000
  XKB indicators:
    00: Caps Lock:   off    01: Num Lock:    off    02: Scroll Lock: off
    03: Compose:     off    04: Kana:        off    05: Sleep:       off
    06: Suspend:     off    07: Mute:        off    08: Misc:        off
    09: Mail:        off    10: Charging:    off    11: Shift Lock:  off
    12: Group 2:     off    13: Mouse Keys:  off
  auto repeat delay:  500    repeat rate:  33
  auto repeating keys:  00ffffffdffffbbf
                        fadfffefffedffff
                        9fffffffffffffff
                        fff7ffffffffffff
  bell percent:  50    bell pitch:  400    bell duration:  100
Pointer Control:
  acceleration:  5/1    threshold:  5
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  yes    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  0    cycle:  0
Colors:
  default colormap:  0x22    BlackPixel:  0x0    WhitePixel:  0xffffff
Font Path:
  /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,built-ins
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 0    Suspend: 0    Off: 0
  DPMS is Enabled
  Monitor is On
```

Needless to stay if I go to Settings > System Settings... and make changes to `Brightness and Lock`, `Power` or `Screen Display` this has no effect on the problem. I don't know what to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I have the exact same problem: After upgrading to 16.04, screen gets blank after 15 seconds. I have a Lenovo e520 laptop.

Answer (score 67):

I have solved this issue. I have no idea why the problem was triggered. I don't know what the problem actually was. I don't know why or how my solution works.

I guessed that the problem was arising because of Display Power Management Signalling, or DPMS. I guessed that DPMS had been turned on by something I'd installed and that it was operating at a default setting of 15 seconds. I guessed that DPMS was turning off the display through the X server after 15 seconds (a default value) of zero activity in order to "manage power". I opened a console and typed

```
xset -dpms
```

This turns off DPMS permanently, not just for the session. The problem promptly went away.

Comment: For me `xset -dpms` uses its impact after reboot. How to make this permanent?

Comment: This issue has appeared again in Ubuntu 17.04 (Gnome 3.24), but this solves it. See this answer for a permanent solution:  https://askubuntu.com/a/324286/115115

Comment: Turning off DPMS seems to be a very bad solution in this case, results in increased power use and faster battery drain on a laptop?

Comment: It works like charm! Thank you so much!

Comment: Worked on Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Adding `xset -dpms` to `~/.bashrc` can be a quick way to make it "permanent".

Comment: I had to restart gnome-shell because it locked up and had this same problem when my session came back (really didn't want to reboot), the solution here fixed the problem for me so that I could continue my work.

Comment: 2022 and this still happens. 18.04 and 20.04.  While `xset -dpms` does "work," it doesn't actually. Using this command will have the screen go blank after the configured time delay, however the monitor(s) never turn off - and thereby continue to use full power. Curious thing: after reboot, everything is always fine. I thought it was some app that was causing this but it's not; it's the system itself. The underlying issue comes to light when you wake the computer after a [normal] display timeout.