# External monitor turning off every 10 seconds Ubuntu 16.04 (and 14.04)

Tags: drivers, 16.04, monitor, vga

My external monitor turning off every 10-13 seconds Ubuntu 16.04 (did that in 14.04 too). Very annoying. Server is a little old, a DELL PE2850, Intel chipset.

I ran: `lspci | grep VGA` to get the below:

```
VGA compatible controller Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] RV100 [Radeon 7000/Radeon VE] VGA controller
```

I also tried the intel-microcode (proprietary) for the controller option, but same result:

Settings > Software & Updates > Additional Drivers >

> Using Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs from intel-microcode (proprietary)

Tried this post command remedy, with a reboot, but no workie:
"Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64bit - screen goes black every 15 seconds"
[ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64bit - screen goes black every 15 seconds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/826190/ubuntu-16-04-lts-64bit-screen-goes-black-every-15-seconds)

```
xset -dpms
```

I've checked cabling also. Any help appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Have you tried a different monitor? What brand is it? Does it have an auto sleep mode? Just want to make sure it's the software and not the hardware first.

Comment: Yes, I am using a ViewSonic now 23", but had the same problem with an older Dell 19". We can't rule that necessarily, but I think it's unlikely having used two monitors. I don't have another one to try at the moment.

Comment: New observation: The 10-13 second blink (screen goes completely black for one second) does not occur at the login shell, only after I log into my account.

Comment: Does it turn off in 12 seconds whilst continuing typing / mouse movement? After it goes dark does moving mouse or pressing a key turn it back on?

Comment: I can still type and move mouse with normal I/O function, ie: drag/resize window, enter text and {Enter} and OS responds. Just the monitor signal turns off for 2 seconds, then back on for 10 seconds, I have now times both on and off sequences.

Comment: Did you read the AMD improvements for Kernel 4.8.1? They mean nothing to me because I use Intel but they might mean something to you.

Comment: I have not, but I guess I am about to. I am not sure that I will get anything out of that, It's probably above my IQ grade, but I'll read it. The CPU is Intel, but the on-board VGA controller is AMD... Whoa, wait a minute, well, I am embarrassed (but also very glad) to say it, the blinking has stopped! in between starting this comment, I was messing around with the video cable and the server bezel, and the blinking stopped! Picture Perfect! Check CABLING first! Which I did, but apparently not enough! Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Don't be silly about Intellectual Quotients (IQ grade) we are all equals here and we are all ignorant about 99.99998% about what witch doctors say or Hillary Clinton promising to reveal information about Aliens today. In all seriousness I googled your problem and didn't find much but I hope yuor comments will bring others out of the woodwork and suggest a specific answer.