# Ubuntu 16.04.01 LTS 64bit - screen goes black after 30 seconds

Tags: screensaver, xserver

A couple days ago I started having this annoying issue:
After about 30 seconds of inactivity, my laptop screen goes blank. Like a screensaver. 
Under System Settings, under "Brightness and Lock", I have unchecked the "Dim" option and the "Turn screen off if inactive for" to "Never". So my screen should not ever go blank.

I found a similar thread here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/826190/ubuntu-16-04-lts-64bit-screen-goes-black-every-15-seconds
. But the solution there is to turn off "dpms". Well, my dpms is turned off and is still happening.

See below the output of the `xset -q` command:

```
    Keyboard Control:
  auto repeat:  on    key click percent:  0    LED mask:  00000000
  XKB indicators:
    00: Caps Lock:   off    01: Num Lock:    off    02: Scroll Lock: off
    03: Compose:     off    04: Kana:        off    05: Sleep:       off
    06: Suspend:     off    07: Mute:        off    08: Misc:        off
    09: Mail:        off    10: Charging:    off    11: Shift Lock:  off
    12: Group 2:     off    13: Mouse Keys:  off
  auto repeat delay:  500    repeat rate:  33
  auto repeating keys:  00ffffffdffffbbf
                        fadfffefffedffff
                        9fffffffffffffff
                        fff7ffffffffffff
  bell percent:  50    bell pitch:  400    bell duration:  100
Pointer Control:
  acceleration:  5/1    threshold:  5
Screen Saver:
  prefer blanking:  no    allow exposures:  yes
  timeout:  0    cycle:  0
Colors:
  default colormap:  0x6e    BlackPixel:  0x0    WhitePixel:  0xffffff
Font Path:
  /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,built-ins
DPMS (Energy Star):
  Standby: 0    Suspend: 0    Off: 0
  DPMS is Disabled
```

Anyone have any suggestion?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: UPDATE: I installed caffeine to try and stop the "screensaver"/blanking - whatever it is, to trigger, but apparently caffeine has no power over it. Even with caffeine running, my screen blanks after 30 seconds of inactivity. Sooo annoying!

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Marian Boricean just go to settigs/power settingsand then you've got a pannel screen with many options where you can tell what to do with your screen power (ex: turn off after 30 minutes)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks Emile, but that was the first thing I tried. Basically whatever I change there, doesn't take effect. I have it turn off after 10 minutes, but it goes off after 30 seconds.